# Visual Studio debugging stored procedure , focus on T-SQL CASE WHEN line by line

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, debugging, stored-procedures

Discovering Visual Studio's ability to step debug on SQL stored procedures and UDF's I want to ask the following: is there any way to step debug between an inner query of a function (line by line) and specifically between a case when of a T-SQL, in order to be sure which one of all conditions is executed with a specific parameter of `@Customercode` ?

I know that 99% will be "no!" and I suppose that an answer to this would be  "Remove the cases from the inner of the query and put them in terms of if ... then of the function... but it seems hard for me to believe that there is no way to do something like this even if an alternative method..

Sometimes you have to debug something that is already written in terms of `CASE WHEN` of the inner query..

The following is a very small example but what if the was a huge query ? There is no way to debug an SQL query line by line and get SQL's definitions of what is SQL doing with your statement ?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_SalutSmallName]   
    (@CustomerCode varchar(50))   
RETURNS varchar(100)   
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @res Varchar(100)  
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @res = CASE  
                      WHEN ESGOPERSON.PersonKind = 0 THEN 'Mr/Mrs'  
                      WHEN ESGOPERSON.PersonKind = 1 AND ESGOPerson.SEX = 1 
                         THEN 'Dear Mr ' + ISNULL(ESGOZCASES.Vocative, '')   
                      WHEN ESGOPERSON.PersonKind = 1 AND ESGOPerson.SEX = 2  
                         THEN 'Dear Mrs ' + ISNULL(ESGOZCASES.Vocative, '')
                      WHEN ESGOPERSON.PersonKind = 1 AND ESGOPerson.SEX = 0 AND ESGOPERSON.fTitleCode = 'Κος' AND ESGOZCASES.Vocative IS NULL
                         THEN 'Mr'  
                      WHEN ESGOPERSON.PersonKind = 1 AND ESGOPerson.SEX = 0 AND ESGOPERSON.fTitleCode = 'Κα' AND ESGOZCASES.Vocative IS NULL
                         THEN 'Mrs'   
                      WHEN ESGOPERSON.PersonKind = 1 AND ESGOPerson.SEX = 0 AND ESGOPERSON.fTitleCode = 'Κος' AND ESGOZCASES.Vocative IS NOT NULL 
                         THEN 'Dear Mr ' + ISNULL(ESGOZCASES.Vocative, '')  
                      WHEN ESGOPERSON.PersonKind = 1 AND ESGOPerson.SEX = 0 AND ESGOPERSON.fTitleCode = 'Κα' AND ESGOZCASES.Vocative IS NOT NULL
                         THEN 'Dear Mrs ' + ISNULL(ESGOZCASES.Vocative, '')  
                      ELSE 'Dear' 
                   END  
        FROM 
            ESFITradeAccount  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            ESGOPerson ON ESFITradeAccount.fPersonCodeGID = ESGOPerson.GID  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            ESGOZCases ON ESGOPerson.FirstName = ESGOZCASES.KeyID 
                       AND ESGOPerson.Sex = ESGOZCases.Gender  
        WHERE   
            ESFITradeAccount.Code = @CustomerCode  
            AND ISNULL(ESGOZCases.KeyType, 1) = 1  

        RETURN @res  
    END
END
```

Comment: Given that this is evaluated once per input row, what do you expect to see? Do you expect the debugger to step through individual rows?

Comment: I expect to see exactly what am seeing in a common debugger , The parameter CustomerCode is already assigned by the user with a value, and the program steps sequensly in each case to see if its true . If not , it exists and procceds to the next case etc. To say it in other words if you have 100 cases on a t-sql query what method would someone use in order for a certain value of CustomerCode  to understand which case of all was true and used for return of results?

Comment: What do you expect to see with `'Κος'` and `'Κα'`? In a lot of collations those will essentially be translated to `'???'` and `'?a'` respectively. Perhaps you mean to use `N'Κος'` and `N'Κα'` instead?

Comment: SQL doesn't run your query the way you write it. It is boiled down to a query plan that tries to do it in the fastest way possible. That's why something like a stepwise debug of case is difficult. Also keep in mind it's evaluated for every row. So you might have a million rows going through that case statement in the order that the query planner thinks is fastest. Also keep in mind that debugging method chaining in C# also doesn't step through the individual methods.

Comment: Could you just create a Unit Test SQL script. Create dummy data to represent each case in the CASE clause (in the example above there would be 8 accounts/people I think), then call the function 8 times (SELECT Code, Fn_SalutSmallName(Code) FROM ESFITradeAccount, or somehing) and check it is returning the correct values.

Comment: @bwakabats i was looking for a handy and fast method in order to debug (SQL CASE WHEN). The truth is that the specific case was posted as a generic problem and is already solved .Thank you by the way for your interest and your idea but if a have 1) to create dummy data 2) Create another Script 3) Run the script as many times as the cases , i dont think that is a handy way .. I still believe that there must be someway to easily step debug maybe with other tools that we dont know !!